# How to fix "return value ignored: 'scanf'" code C6031 in visual studio

Tags: c

I am brand new to coding C (and coding in general) so I have been practicing with some random programs. This one is supposed to determine the cost of a transit ticket (Translink Vancouver prices) based on the user's age and the desired number of "zones" (how far they would like to go). I have compiled it successfully but for some reason which I can not figure out, the scanf functions are being ignored. How do I fix this? Please keep in mind I have only been coding for a few days. Thanks!

```
int main(void) {

int zones;
int age;
double price = 0.00;

printf("Welcome to TransLink cost calculator!\n\n");
printf("Please enter the desired number of zones (1, 2, or 3) you wish to travel: ");
scanf("%d", &zones);

if (zones < 1) {
    printf("Invalid entry\n");
    price = 0.00;
}

else if (zones > 3) {
    printf("Invalid entry\n");
    price = 0.00;
}

else if (zones == 1) {

    printf("Please enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    if (age < 0.00) {
        printf("Invalid Aage");
    }
    else if (age < 5) {
        price = 1.95;
    }
    else if (age >= 5) {
        price = 3.00;
    }
}

else if (zones == 2) {

    printf("Please enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    if (age < 0) {
        printf("Invalid Aage");
    }
    else if (age < 5) {
        price = 2.95;
    }
    else if (age >= 5) {
        price = 4.25;
    }
}

else if (zones == 3) {

    printf("Please enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    if (age < 0) {
        printf("Invalid Aage");
    }
    else if (age < 5) {
        price = 3.95;
    }
    else if (age >= 5) {
        price = 4.75;
    }
}

printf("The price of your ticket is: $%.2f + tax\n", price);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain how you use the value returned by this call `scanf("%d", &age);`. Not the value scanned into `age`, the value returned by that call. The value which tells you whether scanning has succeeded. If you cannot, then you have the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't understand what you are trying to say. I am not sure why it is not working (hence my post here) so if you know how I can fix it and could tell me that would be great, thanks.

Comment: btw. It's not the problem , but age is an int and your are comparing to a float constant: if (age < 0.00) {

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of values processed. You should compare this to the number of variables you're trying to read, to make sure it was successful. e.g. `if (scanf("%d", &age) != 1) { // print error message }`

Comment: Whatever you did to make visual studio complain about ignoring `scanf()`s return value. Please teach it to as many people as you can.

Answer (score 6):

A bit too much here to put in a comment.

I use a version of Visual C but it never complains about the return value from `scanf` not being used. What it *does* is to complain that `scanf` is *unsafe* and *deprecated*, when it isn't.

MS thinks I should be using its own "safer" version `scanf_s` which is even tricker to use and IMO no safer at all – because it is not a like-for-like replacement but takes different arguments, and so it is easy to make mistakes in using it.

One consequent problem is the compiler issues a warning for *every* use of `scanf` (and some other functions)  which obscures other warnings. I deal with it as advised by adding a `#define` before the first library header inclusion.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
```

There are other matters which MS warns about too, and I actually place three `#defines` at the start of each file:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE  
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE

#include <stdio.h>
```

And now the relevant warnings are easy to see.

Comment: I fully agree with the advice to disable MSVC's advice to use their pseudo-Annex K functions; however, the `scanf` family _are_ unsafe, for several reasons, most importantly that `%s` is just as dangerous as `gets`, and that numeric conversion has undefined behavior on _numeric_ input overflow (yes, that means the C library is allowed to _crash_ just because someone typed too many digits).

Comment: @zwol yes, but C is unsafe anyway. You can create a segfault very easily by exceeding array bounds. My point was that MS's `scanf_s` isn't really any better than `scanf` - both can cause damage when used incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

From documentation of `scanf()` (e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

> Return value
>   1-3) Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.

You are ignoring that return value.

Replace

```
scanf("%d", &age);
```

by

```
int NofScannedArguments=0; /* Number of arguments which were
successfully filled by the most recent call to scanf() */

/* ...  do above once, at the start of your function */

NofScannedArguments= scanf("%d", &age);

/* check the return value to find out whether scanning was successful */
if(NofScannedArguments!=1) /* should be one number */
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* failure, assumptions of program are not met */
}
```

... to find out whether scanning succeeded.
Not doing so is a bad idea and worth the warning you got.

In case you want to handle failures more gracefully, e.g. prompt the user again,
use a loop and read http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html about the pitfalls you may encounter.
I am not saying you should NOT use scanf, the article explains a lot about using scanf, while trying to convince you not to.

Comment: If you'd used a more reasonable variable name than the essay you chose…  I often use `rv` (return value) — I accept that's too minimal, but `retval` is a possibility, with an underscore in the middle if desired.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think I know what you mean. But in this case OP needs all the super-explicit explanation they can get. Let me see whether I can get both needs covered. There. Deal?

Comment: IMO this (making a variable) is not really useful as it really does nothing. in competitive programming at least

Comment: @JMuzhen I think I know what you mean. But in this case OP needs all the super-explicit explanation they can get.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and asked several times in other threads.

To suppress individual C6031 warning, I cast the function w/ (void).

Example:

```
double x;
(void)scanf("%lf", &x);
```

this way, I can "mark" that I'm intentionally ignoring the return value of the function (=scanf). This is useful for the functions such as [InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsectionandspincount), which always succeeds and returns non-zero value, worth ignoring safely.

This seems better to suppress C6031 entirely.

Answer (score -1):

Using C++ functions for input is SO much easier.  Instead of scanf and printf one could use cin and cout as the following demonstrates:

```
#include <iostream>  // for cin and cout use

int main()
{
    int zones;

    std::cout << "Enter zones" << std::endl;  // endl is similar to \n
    std::cin >> zones;
    std::cout << "Your zones is " << zones << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, the author was clearly wanting to know how to use `scanf` and `printf`; secondly you are clearly not experienced with the `scanf` and `printf` functions, as although they may be harder to use, they run much faster than `std::cin` and `std:cout`.

Comment: This is not what author asked